# Wrong Data Is Inserted in Access Database with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a small problem regarding the Access Database when it has data inserted.

I have a button that inserts data when it's clicked. Here it is the code:

```
string[] read = File.ReadAllLines("Harta_Distantelor.txt");

string[] orase = { "Constanta", "Varna", "Burgas", "Istambul", "Kozlu", "Samsun", "Batumi", "Sokhumi", "Soci", "Anapa", "Yalta", "Sevastopol", "Odessa" };

 OleDbCommand cmd;

        for (int i = 0; i < read.Length; i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            string[] numbers = read[i].Split(' ');
            while (j < read.Length)
            {
                //cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Distante SET ID_Port='" + (i + 1) + "', ID_Port_Destinatie='" + (j + 1) + "', Nume_Port_Destinatie='" + orase[j] + "' WHERE Distanta='" + numbers[j] + "' ", conn);
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Distante]([ID_Port], [ID_Port_Destinatie], [Nume_Port_Destinatie], [Distanta]) VALUES ('" + (i + 1).ToString() + "', '" + (j + 1).ToString() + "', '" + orase[j] + "', '" + numbers[j] + "')", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                j++;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that instead of having something like ID_Port=1, ID_Port_Destinatie=1, Nume_Port_Destinatie="Constanta", ID_Port=1, ID_Port_Destinatie=2, Nume_Port_Destinatie="Varna" and so on, I get this...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjMQm.png

The file "Harta_Distantelor.txt" is a matrix that has the distances, so that's why I tried to split every number from a line(`string[] numbers = read[i].Split(' ');`). I have to mention that [Distanta] data is correctly inserted, but the rest of the data is totally randomly inserted. I tried to figure out where the problem is, but I have no clue. Where is the mistake? What should I try to do in order to have the data showed correctly?

Comment: I don't know c#, but I'm guessing it might be something to do with `while (j < read.Length)`. Is read.Length the number of lines in the input file? Shouldn't `j` be looping for the number of entries in your `numbers` array?

Comment: @Skippy read.Length is the number of lines in the input file. But I changed to numbers.Length, and the result is the same. Anyway, read.Length has the same size as numbers.Length, so it made no difference.

Comment: OK, a few suggestions. Firstly, you have given us a picture of what your actual result is. Can you also show us (in table form) what you're expecting. It would also be helpful to see the format of the input data file `Harta_Distantelor.txt`. Secondly, can you put any debug statements in to show the values of your variables at various stages of the operation? For example what are `i`, `j`, `orase[j]` and `numbers[j]` just before you run the `INSERT`?

Comment: Also, I am intrigued that `read.Length` has the same value as `numbers.Length` - if `read.Length` is the number of lines in the file and `numbers` is an array of the entries on one line of the file, what does `numbers.Length` even mean? Is it the number of entries in the array?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a table called HartaDistantelor with columns for ID_Port, ID_Port_Destinatie, and Distanta

2.) Fill the table HartaDistantelor with your matrix values. You may be able to copy and paste directly into Access

3.) Create a table called Orase with columns for ID_Port and Nume_Port

4.) Fill the table Orase with the 13 values from your array. It should look like this:

```
1    Constanta
2    Varna
3    Burgas
4    ...
```

5.) Change your code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Distante (ID_Port, ID_Port_Destinatie, Nume_Port_Destinatie, Distanta) SELECT " + (i + 1).ToString() + ", " + (j + 1).ToString() + ", o.Nume_Port, h.Distanta FROM Orase o JOIN HartaDistantelor h ON h.ID_Port = o.ID_Port WHERE h.ID_Port = i AND h.ID_Port_Destinatie = j", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

My approach joins records from two tables using ID values that match. I don't think you made any mistake, but used a method with more complexity than was necessary.